# how to get authorization code for Box in python

Tags: python, box-api

I was stuck in 'Getting the Access Token' part. In the documentation, I need a 'code'. But how can I get the authorization code? I'm using python.

```
    authorize_url = 'https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID'

    def myRequest(path, method=None, options=None):
        response = requests.request(method, path, **options)
        return json.dumps(response.json())

    code = myRequest(
        path=authorize_url,
        method='GET',
        options={
            'headers':{
                'response_type': 'code',
                'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
                }
        }
    )
```

Comment: Can you show us what is your code as of right now? So we can help you fix it.

Comment: def request(path, method=None, options=None):
    response = requests.request(method, path, **options)
    return json.dumps(response.json())

Comment: code = requests(
    path=authorize_url,
    method='GET',
    options={
        'headers':{
            'response_type': 'code',
            'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
            }
    }
)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a module to make HTTP requests e.g. [requests](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDMQFjAA&url=http://python-requests.org/&ei=bABWUeDmIsaXiAKQ3IHABw&usg=AFQjCNEPNMe0O8m1A2DNQhDhvix4qFygsw&bvm=bv.44442042,d.cGE) or [urllib](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDMQFjAA&url=http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html&ei=TgBWUcrKIaWqiALmwoGQCQ&usg=AFQjCNHsuNbKzXZ9czlCxbyWmxjYG6EgJg&bvm=bv.44442042,d.cGE) and follow the instructions as indicated [here](http://developers.box.com/oauth).

I have a very simple Flask app set up here: https://github.com/seanrose/box-oauth2-example

The 'code' is returned to your app after you send the user to Box's authorization URL.

Comment: Is this the correct way? I use this to get token which is all right. But I have tried the whole day, cannot get the code, sorry...    

def request(path, method=None, options=None):
    response = requests.request(method, path, **options)
    return json.dumps(response.json())

code = requests(
    path=authorize_url,
    method='GET',
    options={
        'headers':{
            'response_type': 'code',
            'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
            }
    }
)

Comment: What I did is, first, print a url, user open it, until click allow, I get the code, then use code to get token, finally, use token to access  user's content. but now I cannot get the code. If I manually set code, everything works fine.